# Angular-6 based on the select inputbox and select dropdown not showing properly

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular6, dropdown, inputbox

This question is maybe asked, but that is not solving my issue.

The `drop-down` of key contains `database`, `desktop` and `account`. Based on the drop-down of key the value `drop-down` and `inputbox` will be changed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zahevb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

> My issue: When I click 1st row it seems good.
> But when I move on to 2nd row the data append not properly. And when I select `account` previuos row drop-down also changed as `inputbox`

**Eg:**

1. In 1st row I select Database,value should append ['mysql', 'oracle', 'mongo'] in `drop-down`
2. In 2nd row I select Desktop, value should append ['dell', 'lenovo', 'hp']
3. In 3rd row I select Account the `inputbox` will show

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  dynamicArray: Array<any> = [];
  newDynamic: any = {};
  dbValue = ["mysql", "oracle", "mongo"];
  desktopValue = [{'id':'1', 'name':'dell'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'lenovo'}, {'id':'3', 'name':'hp'}];
  isdbShow:boolean = false;
  isdesktopShow:boolean = false;
  isaccountShow:boolean = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newDynamic = { title1: "", title2: "", dropdownDataDb: [], dropdownDataDesktop: [] };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
  }
  addRow(index) {
    this.newDynamic = { title1: "", title2: "", dropdownDataDb: [], dropdownDataDesktop: [] };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
    console.log(this.dynamicArray);
    return true;
  }

  deleteRow(index) {
    if (this.dynamicArray.length == 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.dynamicArray.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    }
  }

  changed(value, index) {
    let dropdownDataDb;
    let dropdownDataDesktop;
    if (value == 1) {
      this.isdbShow = true;
      this.isdesktopShow = false;
      this.isaccountShow = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownDataDb = this.dbValue;
    }

    if (value == 2) {
      this.isdbShow = false;
      this.isdesktopShow = true;
      this.isaccountShow = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownDataDesktop = this.desktopValue;
    }

    if (value == 3) {
      this.isdbShow = false;
      this.isdesktopShow = false;
      this.isaccountShow = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.componet.html**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>key</th>
                <th>value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let dynamic of dynamicArray; let i = index;">
                <td (click)="deleteRow(i)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title1" class="form-control" #sel (change)="changed(sel.value, i)">
            <option [value]='1'>Database</option>
            <option [value]='2'>Desktop</option>
            <option [value]='3'>Account</option>
          </select>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- show db data -->
                    <select *ngIf="isdbShow" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownDataDb;">{{data}}</option>
          </select>
                    <!-- show desktop data -->
                    <select *ngIf="isdesktopShow" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownDataDesktop;">{{data?.name ? data?.name : data}}</option>
          </select>

          <!-- show account data -->
          <input *ngIf="isaccountShow" type="text" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td (click)="addRow(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ts code`

```js
dynamicArray: Array<any> = [];
  newDynamic: any = {};
  dbValue = ["mysql", "oracle", "mongo"];
  desktopValue = [
    { id: "1", name: "dell" },
    { id: "2", name: "lenovo" },
    { id: "3", name: "hp" }
  ];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.newDynamic = {
      title1: "",
      title2: "",
      dropdownDataDb: [],
      dropdownDataDesktop: [],
      isDropDown: true
    };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
  }
  addRow(index) {
    this.newDynamic = {
      title1: "",
      title2: "",
      dropdownDataDb: [],
      dropdownDataDesktop: [],
      isDropDown: true,
      isText: false
    };
    this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
    console.log(this.dynamicArray);
    return true;
  }

  deleteRow(index) {
    if (this.dynamicArray.length == 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.dynamicArray.splice(index, 1);
      return true;
    }
  }

  changed(value: any, index: any) {
    console.log(this.dynamicArray[index].title1);
    if (value == 1) {
      this.dynamicArray[index].isDropDown = true;
      this.dynamicArray[index].isText = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownDataDb = this.dbValue;
    }

    if (value == 2) {
      this.dynamicArray[index].isDropDown = true;
      this.dynamicArray[index].isText = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].dropdownDataDesktop = this.desktopValue;
    }

    if (value == 3) {
      this.dynamicArray[index].isDropDown = false;
      this.dynamicArray[index].isText = true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 5%">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>key</th>
                <th>value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let dynamic of dynamicArray; let i = index;">
                <td (click)="deleteRow(i)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title1" class="form-control" #sel (change)="changed(sel.value, i)">
            <option [value]='1'>Database</option>
            <option [value]='2'>Desktop</option>
            <option [value]='3'>Account</option>
          </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- show db data -->
                    <select *ngIf="dynamicArray[i].title1 == 1 && dynamic?.isDropDown" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownDataDb;">{{data}}</option>
          </select>
                    <!-- show desktop data -->
                    <select *ngIf="dynamicArray[i].title1 == 2 && dynamic?.isDropDown" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
            <option *ngFor="let data of dynamicArray[i].dropdownDataDesktop;">{{data?.name ? data?.name : data}}</option>
          </select>

                    <!-- show account data -->
                    <input *ngIf="dynamicArray[i].title1 == 3 && dynamic?.isText" type="text" [(ngModel)]="dynamicArray[i].title2" class="form-control">
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td (click)="addRow(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598783/angular-6-show-last-12-months-with-year-reverse-order-in-select-option

Comment: hi bro please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518605/bootstrap-4-selectpicker-not-displaying-in-angular-6 i set boutry also

Comment: Hi bro if you are free please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985275/angular-6-based-on-the-select-multi-select-dropdown-show-and-hide-not-working-pr