# Bootstrap 4 selectpicker not displaying in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, select, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

This question already asked but it wont work for me.
Am using `Bootstrap 4` `selectpicker` in my `angular 6`, but it is not displaying. In `css` it shows `display: none !important;`

[image]

**My sample code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**demo** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmyy6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: My first question is: is it an Angular project? If it is Angular, then why  are you adding scripts and stylesheets like that? Second question is: did you initiate the `selectPicker` like this in your code? `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`

Comment: @Shuvo:Thanks for response, Yes it is Angular 6. And I added that script in stackblitz but still it is not showing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmyy6e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hello please check this link to setup bootsrap in angular project "https://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-bootstrap-4-to-angular-6-application/"

Comment: To add jquery in angular project "npm install jquery --save" and add "scripts" :["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"] in angular.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add these links in head part` on index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
```

`Add these links in after body part completed` on index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

`Add below content in` app.component.html page

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-selected-text-format="count">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** no need to add $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

Comment: Hi Ravi Ashara am using `bootstrap 4.0.0` but it is still not showing

Comment: I added your code as you said css files in inside head, and js file in after body.

Comment: @RameshS Welcome

Comment: @RameshS i show  your code you add external library link in `app.component.html` but external library always added in index.html file

Comment: Hi Bro please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670248/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-not-working-in-angular-6

Answer (score 1):

You can just add this to your css:

```
.selectpicker {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Here is the the updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i2ozz2?file=src/app/app.component.css

Since you are developing in Angular, I would suggest you to check `@ng-select/ng-select` package. It has so many useful features, and you can just install a package and use it.

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fauxb2?file=src/multi-select-hidden-example.component.html

Comment: Yes it is showing now. But am expecting like this https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#basic-examples

Comment: I want to multi select with checkbox , Actually in my code selectpicker css not working properly

Comment: I updated answer with new example. Can you check it? It uses `@ng-select/ng-select` package. I will try later to make a working example with `bootstrap-select`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually in my project not able to install modules via npm (I don't have permission), That's why am using Bootstrap multi select. I give you upvote

Comment: hi bro please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67670248/dynamically-load-external-javascript-file-not-working-in-angular-6

Comment: I saw that someone already answered with working solution.