# Dynamically load external javascript file not working in angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, multi-select, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am using `Angular 6`, am trying to add [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/index.html#getting-started) in my project. But here am facing some issue `bootstrap-multiselect.js` not loading in page.

So am tying to add dynamically add this `bootstrap-multiselect.js` file, but it is not loading please help me on this

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <my-app>loading</my-app>
      <!-- Inclusion of sgwt widgets -->
      <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
   </body>
   <!-- Multiselect code -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap.bundle-4.5.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/prettify.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({
              includeSelectAllOption: false,
              enableFiltering: true,
              includeFilterClearBtn: false,
              enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true,
            });
        });
   </script>
   <!-- Multiselect code -->
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() { 
     this.loadScript('http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js');
   }

   public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Still it is showing like this:

[image]

> Please help on this am new in `angular 6`. This question maybe already asked but that is not solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've imported the libraries like you did from that website but only changed jquery.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-4.5.2.min.css"
    type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/bootstrap-example.min.css"
    type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/prettify.min.css"
    type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/css/fontawesome-5.15.1-web/all.css" type="text/css">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/bootstrap.bundle-4.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/docs/js/prettify.min.js">
  </script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Here's [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-include-wtcgqv?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Inside an ngb-modal: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-include-b3rksd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will implement your code

Comment: let me know how it goes

Comment: Hi am facing `error typeerror $(...).multiselect is not a function`

Comment: My folder structure like this https://ibb.co/x3rQ4Pt I added your `ngAfterViewInit()` code in my child component please help me to solve this

Comment: Hi, I haven't included the type definition files but added a `declare var $: any;` in my app.component.ts to suppress the type errors. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I added `declare var $: any;` in my child component

Comment: umm then that error message shouldn't appear. Can you try `($(...) as any).multiselect` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232853/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-eko).

Comment: Hi bro now in I put console.log($('#example-getting-started')) it showing some data in console please check this url https://ibb.co/jJt2jq2

Comment: No bro before console.log not showing but now it is showing

Comment: Haha nice! Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Hello bro how to remove `keys` in `value` attribute please check this image https://ibb.co/27qmXkn here automatically `value` attribute added keys. eg: `value="0: 'rc-srvparvvae1478'"` . I just want `value="rc-srvparvvae1478"`. how to change this one. My code https://ibb.co/F8C34Yx

Comment: Hello, you should really ask a separate question :-) there're other people on Stackoverflow that can help

Comment: hi bro if you are free please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67985275/angular-6-based-on-the-select-multi-select-dropdown-show-and-hide-not-working-pr